# Perf Stat vs Perf Record

Tags: perf

I am confused about the difference between `perf record` and `perf stat` when it comes to counting events like page-faults, cache-misses and anything else from `perf list`. I have 2 questions below the answer to "Question 1" might also help answer "Question 2" but I wrote them out explicitly in the case that it doesn't.

Question 1:
It is my understanding that `perf stat` gets a "summary" of counts but when used with the -I option gets the counts at the specified millisecond interval. With this option does it sum up the counts over the interval or get the average over the interval, or something else entirely? I assume it is summed up. The [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat) states it is aggregated but I guess that could mean either.

Question 2:
Why doesn't `perf stat -e <event1> -I 1000 sleep 5` give about the same counts as if I summed up the counts over each second for the following command `perf record -e <event1> -F 1000 sleep 5`?

For example if I use "page-faults" as the event for event1 I get the following outputs I have listed below under each command. (I am assuming the period field is the counts for the event in `perf record`'s perf.data file)

PERF STAT

```
    perf stat -e page-faults -I 1000 sleep 5
    #           time             counts unit events
         1.000252928                 54      page-faults                                                 
         2.000498389      <not counted>      page-faults                                                 
         3.000569957      <not counted>      page-faults                                                 
         4.000659987      <not counted>      page-faults                                                 
         5.000837864                  2      page-faults
```

PERF RECORD

```
    perf record -e page-faults -F 1000 sleep 5
    [ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
    [ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.016 MB perf.data (6 samples) ]
    perf script -F period
             1
             1
             1
             5
            38
           164
```

I expected that if I summed up the counts from `perf stat` I would get the same as the sum from `perf record`. If I use the -c option with `perf record` and give an argument of 1 I do get a close match. Is this just a coincidence because of the relatively low number of page faults?

References I have used so far:

- [brendangregg's perf blog](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Events)
- The perf record and stat links on [this page](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) mentioned above as "perf wiki"
- I dug around [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13/source/tools/perf) to see how and when perf record actually records vs when it writes to perf.data.

Thanks in advance for any and all insight you can provide.

Comment: aggregated means summed up.  A longer `-I` interval for `perf stat` will give more counts, for anything that happens at a steady rate (like `cycles`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, your test case of using `sleep` and `page-faults` is not an ideal test case. There should be no page fault events during the sleep duration, you you can't really expect anything interesting. For the sake of easier reasoning I suggest to use the `ref-cycles` (hardware) event and a busy workload such as `awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'`.

> Question 1: It is my understanding that perf stat gets a "summary" of
>   counts but when used with the -I option gets the counts at the
>   specified millisecond interval. With this option does it sum up the
>   counts over the interval or get the average over the interval, or
>   something else entirely? I assume it is summed up.

Yes. The values are just summed up. You can confirm that by testing:

```
$ perf stat -e ref-cycles -I 1000 timeout 10s awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'
#           time             counts unit events
 1.000105072      2,563,666,664      ref-cycles                                                  
 2.000267991      2,577,462,550      ref-cycles                                                  
 3.000415395      2,577,211,936      ref-cycles                                                  
 4.000543311      2,577,240,458      ref-cycles                                                  
 5.000702131      2,577,525,002      ref-cycles                                                  
 6.000857663      2,577,156,088      ref-cycles                                                  

[ ... snip ... ]
[ Note that it may not be as nicely consistent on all systems due dynamic frequency scaling ]

$ perf stat -e ref-cycles -I 3000 timeout 10s awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }' 
#           time             counts unit events
 3.000107921      7,736,108,718      ref-cycles                                                  
 6.000265186      7,732,065,900      ref-cycles                                                  
 9.000372029      7,728,302,192      ref-cycles
```

> Question 2: Why doesn't `perf stat -e <event1> -I 1000 sleep 5` give
>   about the same counts as if I summed up the counts over each second
>   for the following command `perf record -e <event1> -F 1000 sleep 5`?

`perf stat -I` is in *milliseconds*, whereas `perf record -F` is in *HZ* (1/s), so the corresponding command to `perf stat -I 1000` is `perf record -F 1`. In fact with our more stable event/workload, this looks better:

```
$ perf stat -e ref-cycles -I 1000 timeout 10s awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'
#           time             counts unit events
 1.000089518      2,578,694,534      ref-cycles                                                  
 2.000203872      2,579,866,250      ref-cycles                                                  
 3.000294300      2,579,857,852      ref-cycles                                                  
 4.000390273      2,579,964,842      ref-cycles                                                  
 5.000488375      2,577,955,536      ref-cycles                                                  
 6.000587028      2,577,176,316      ref-cycles                                                  
 7.000688250      2,577,334,786      ref-cycles                                                  
 8.000785388      2,577,581,500      ref-cycles                                                  
 9.000876466      2,577,511,326      ref-cycles                                                  
10.000977965      2,577,344,692      ref-cycles                                                  
10.001195845            466,674      ref-cycles    

$ perf record -e ref-cycles -F 1 timeout 10s awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.008 MB perf.data (17 samples) ]

$ perf script -F time,period        
3369070.273722:          1 
3369070.273755:          1 
3369070.273911:       3757 
3369070.273916:    3015133 
3369070.274486:          1 
3369070.274556:          1 
3369070.274657:       1778 
3369070.274662:    2196921 
3369070.275523: 47192985748 
3369072.663696: 2578692405 
3369073.663547: 2579122382 
3369074.663609: 2580015300 
3369075.664085: 2579873741 
3369076.664433: 2578638211 
3369077.664379: 2578378119 
3369078.664175: 2578166440 
3369079.663896: 2579238122
```

So you see, eventually the results are stable also for `perf record -F`. Unfortunately the documentation of `perf record` is very poor. You can learn what the settings `-c` and `-F` mean by looking at the documentation of the underlying system call `man perf_event_open`:

> `sample_period`, `sample_freq`    A  "sampling" event is one that
>   generates an overflow notification every N events, where N is given by
>   `sample_period`.  A    sampling event has `sample_period` > 0.  When
>   an overflow occurs, requested data is recorded in the mmap buffer. 
>   The `sample_type` field controls what data is recorded on each
>   overflow.
>
> `sample_freq` can be used if you wish to use frequency rather than
>   period.  In this case, you set the freq flag.  **The kernel will
>   adjust the sampling period to try and achieve the desired rate.**  The
>   rate of adjustment is a timer tick.

So while `perf stat` uses an internal timer to read the value of the counter every `-i` milliseconds, `perf record` sets an event overflow counter to take a sample every `-c` events. That means it takes a sample every `N` events (e.g. every `N` `page-fault` or `cycles`). With `-F`, it it tries to regulate this overflow value to achieve the desired frequency. It tries different values and tunes it up/down accordingly. This eventually works for counters with a stable rate, but will get erratic results for dynamic events.

Comment: `cat /dev/urandom` is unusual because it spends almost all of its CPU time inside system calls.  (This can be useful to test whether `perf` is measuring only user-space or not, though, e.g. `cycles:u` vs. `cycles`).  `awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'` is an infinite loop in user-space.

Comment: @Zulan Thank you for your answer. I did know that -F was in hertz and I should have clarified this point. I was wondering why if I add up all the record samples over a 1 second they don't add up to the number stat -I 1000 gives for that same second. I assume from your answer it was because my test case was poor. If that is the case then why does `perf record` record any page-faults during a sleep operation. I could maybe see if I did the -a option but I didn't so how are there any?

Comment: `perf record` should not report any events *during* the sleep, but there is work at the beginning and end. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809347/perf-startup-overhead-why-does-a-simple-static-executable-which-performs-mov

Comment: @PeterCordes excellent point. It was including kernel for my example, probably due to `perf_event_paranoid=-1`