# Benchmarking - How to count number of instructions sent to CPU to find consumed MIPS

Tags: performance, assembly, profiling, cpu, benchmarking

Consider I have a software and want to study its behavior using a [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) approach. I have a 3.0GHz CPU with 2 sockets and 4 cores. As you know, in order to find out instructions per second (IPS) we have to use the following formula:

```
IPS = sockets*(cores/sockets)*clock*(instructions/cycle)
```

At first, I wanted to find number of instructions per cycle for my specific algorithm. Then I realised its almost impossible to count it using a block-box approach and I need to do in-depth analysis of the algorithm.

But now, I have two question: Regardless of what kind of software is running on my machine and its cpu usage, is there any way to count number of instructions per second sent to the CPU (Millions of instructions per second (MIPS))? And is it possible to find the type of instruction set (add, compare, in, jump, etc) ?

Any piece of script or tool recommendation would be appreciated (in any language).

Comment: `perf stat ./my_program` on Linux will use CPU performance counters to record how many instructions it ran, and how many core clock cycles it took.  (And how much CPU time it used, so you can get MIPS).

Comment: @PeterCordes Perfect! Thanks a lot. How can I get real-time information at run-time?

Comment: Do you mean from within the program, to profile only part of it?  There's a `perf` API where you can do `perf_event_open` or something.  Or use a different library for direct access to the HW perf counters.  Normally I microbenchmark code that I'm tuning by putting the hot loop in a program by itself that runs lots of iters, so I don't normally do that.

Comment: re: types of instructions: Intel CPUs at least have a counter for branch instructions, but other types aren't differentiated other than FP instructions.  e.g. with `ocperf.py` you can `ocperf.py stat -e task_clock,cycles,instructions,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_single,fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_double,uops_executed.x87 ./my_program`  For exact dynamic instruction counts, you might use an instrumentation tool like Intel PIN, if you're on x86.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perf stat --all-user ./my_program` on Linux will use CPU performance counters to record how many user-space instructions it ran, and how many core clock cycles it took. And how much CPU time it used, and will calculate average instructions per core clock cycle for you, e.g.

```
3,496,129,612      instructions:u            #    2.61  insn per cycle
```

It calculates IPC for you; this is usually more interesting than instructions per *second*.  `uops` per clock is usually even more interesting in terms of how close you are to maxing out the front-end, though.  **You can manually calculate MIPS from `instructions` and `task-clock`.**  For most other events perf prints a comment with a per-second rate.

(If you don't use `--all-user`, you can use `perf stat -e task-clock:u,instructions:u` , ... to have those specific events count in user-space only, while other events can count always, including inside interrupt handlers and system calls.)

But see [How to calculate MIPS using perf stat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363242/how-to-calculate-mips-using-perf-stat) for more detail on `instructions / task-clock` vs. `instructions / elapsed_time` if you do actually want total or average MIPS across cores, and counting sleep or not.

---

For an example output from using it on a tiny microbenchmark loop in a static executable, see [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all)

> How can I get real-time information at run-time

Do you mean from within the program, to profile only part of it? There's a perf API where you can do `perf_event_open` or something. Or use a different library for direct access to the HW perf counters.

`perf stat` is great for microbenchmarking a loop that you've isolated into a stand-alone program that just runs the hot loop for a second or so.

Or maybe you mean something else.  **`perf stat -I 1000 ... ./a.out` will print counter values every 1000 ms (1 second), to see how program behaviour changes in real time** with whatever time window you want (down to 10ms intervals).

`sudo perf top` is system-wide, slightly like Unix `top`

There's also `perf record --timestamp` to record a timestamp with each event sample.  `perf report -D` might be useful along with this.  See http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html, he mentions something about `-T` (`--timestamp`).  I haven't really used this; I mostly isolate single loops I'm tuning into a static executable I can run under `perf stat`.

---

> And is it possible to find the type of instruction set (add, compare, in, jump, etc)?

Intel x86 CPUs at least have a counter for branch instructions, but other types aren't differentiated, other than FP instructions.  This is probably common to most architectures that have perf counters at all.

For Intel CPUs, there's [ocperf.py](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools), a wrapper for `perf` with symbolic names for more microarchitectural events.  (Update: plain `perf` now knows the names of most uarch-specific counters so you don't need `ocperf.py` anymore.)

`perf stat -e task_clock,cycles,instructions,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_single,fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_double,uops_executed.x87 ./my_program`

**It's not designed to tell you what instructions are running, you can already tell that from tracing execution**.  Most instructions are fully pipelined, so the interesting thing is which ports have the most pressure.  The exception is the divide/sqrt unit: there's a counter for `arith.divider_active`: "*Cycles when divide unit is busy executing divide or square root operations. Accounts for integer and floating-point operations*".  The divider isn't fully pipelined, so a new `divps` or `sqrtps` can't always start even if no older uops are ready to execute on port 0.  (http://agner.org/optimize/)

Related: [linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031210/linux-perf-how-to-interpret-and-find-hotspots) for using `perf` to identify hotspots.  Especially using top-down profiling you have `perf` sample the call-stack to see which functions make a lot of expensive child calls.  (I mention this in case that's what you *really* wanted to know, rather than instruction mix.)

**Related:**

- [How do I determine the number of x86 machine instructions executed in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355631/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-x86-machine-instructions-executed-in-a-c-progra)
- [How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243626/how-to-characterize-a-workload-by-obtaining-the-instruction-type-breakdown)
- [How do I monitor the amount of SIMD instruction usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104698/how-do-i-monitor-the-amount-of-simd-instruction-usage)

---

**For exact dynamic instruction counts, you might use an instrumentation tool like Intel PIN, if you're on x86**. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.

`perf stat` counts for the `instructions:u` hardware even should also be more or less exact, and is in practice very repeatable across runs of the same program doing the same work.

On recent Intel CPUs, there's HW support for recording which way conditional / indirect branches went, so you can reconstruct exactly which instructions ran in which order, assuming no self-modifying code and that you can still read any JIT buffers.  [Intel PT](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/18/processor-tracing).

---

Sorry I don't know what the equivalents are on AMD CPUs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind helps. This information really helped. My intention is to benchmark an application using a balck-box approach, so I can’t use the API from inside the app itself. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichelGokan: I forgot to mention `perf stat -I` for "real-time" updates; updated my answer.

Comment: `perf stat ./my_program` did not return calculated `MIPS` please see example output(https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/809d075e2d266cbbb255f2d2f60ba041). In order to calculate `MIPS` should I do following  `instructions/seconds_time_elapsed`. @PeterCordes

Comment: @alper: yes.  For most counters `perf` calculates per-second for you, but for instructions it calculates average instructions per clock, not second.  That's usually more interesting anyway.