# How to calculate MIPS using perf stat

Tags: performance, profiling, mips, cpu, perf

Following [answer about Benchmarking - How to count number of instructions sent to CPU to find consumed MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110233/2402577) suggest that:

> `perf stat ./my_program` on Linux will use CPU performance counters to
>   record how many instructions it ran, and how many core clock cycles it
>   took. (And how much CPU time it used, and will calculate MIPS for
>   you).

---

An example generates following output which does not contain calculated `MIPS` information.

```
 Performance counter stats for './hello.py':

       1452.607792 task-clock (msec)         #    0.997 CPUs utilized
               327 context-switches          #    0.225 K/sec
               147 cpu-migrations            #    0.101 K/sec
            35,548 page-faults               #    0.024 M/sec
     2,254,593,107 cycles                    #    1.552 GHz                     [26.64%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend
     1,652,281,933 instructions              #    0.73  insns per cycle         [38.87%]
       353,431,039 branches                  #  243.308 M/sec                   [37.95%]
        18,536,723 branch-misses             #    5.24% of all branches         [38.06%]
       612,338,241 L1-dcache-loads           #  421.544 M/sec                   [25.93%]
        41,746,028 L1-dcache-load-misses     #    6.82% of all L1-dcache hits   [25.71%]
        25,531,328 LLC-loads                 #   17.576 M/sec                   [26.39%]
         1,846,241 LLC-load-misses           #    7.23% of all LL-cache hits    [26.26%]

       1.456531157 seconds time elapsed
```

**[Q]** How could I calculate `MIPS` correctly from output of `perf stat`? In order to calculate MIPS should I do following `instructions/seconds_time_elapsed` from the values obtained from `perf stat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously just instructions / seconds. (divided by 1 million to scale for the Mega metric prefix.)

Using the total elapsed time will give you MIPS for the whole program, total across all cores, and counting any time spent sleeping / waiting against it.

Task-clock will count total CPU time used on all cores, so it will give you the *average* MIPS across all cores used, not counting any time spent sleeping.  (`task-clock:u` would count only user-space time, but `task-clock` counts time spent in the kernel as well.)

Comment: As I understand `task-clock` is equivalent for average MIPS across all cores, right? So as I understand, it will be more efficient to use `task-clock` instead of `instructions / seconds_elapsed_seconds` in order to ignore any time spent sleeping / waiting. @Peter Cordes

Comment: @alper: it's not a question of "efficiency", it's just 2 different things you might want to measure.  `instructions / task-clock` is average MIPS across all cores, counting only time that wasn't spent sleeping.  e.g. `perf stat sleep 1` will only show a `task-clock` of ~0.4 milliseconds, but an elapsed time of 1 second.  Code that has I/O waits or hard page faults is losing time not executing any instructions during those intervals, so it's certainly reasonable to count that time against it.  Or time spent sleeping waiting for mutexes in multi-threaded code.

Comment: Both have a large difference between each other. `perf stat sleep 1` returns `1 msec` for the task-clock, which is 0.001 seconds. So it will be for elapsed time `instructions / 1` or task-clock `instructions / 0.001` which is around 1000 times smaller. @Peter Cordes

Comment: @alper: exactly.  `sleep` uses very little CPU time to start up, dynamic-link its libraries, and make a system call.  But it spends significant time sleeping so the total wall-clock time is high.  During most of the elapsed time, the CPU is available for other tasks, but the `sleep` task itself is not complete.  `cp` of a large file would be similar: most of the time spent waiting for I/O.

Comment: The `u` and `k` modifiers (and any other modifier) don't seem to work on the `task-clock` and `cpu-clock` events. Both user and kernel times are always included.