# How do I determine the number of x86 machine instructions executed in a C program?

Tags: c, x86, profiling, instruction-set

I'm currently working on a homework problem that asks me to find out the number of machine code instructions that are executed when running a short program I wrote in C.

The question says I am able to use whatever tools I want to figure it out, but I'm fairly new to C and have very little idea how to go about this.

What types of tools do I need to figure this out?

Comment: On what OS are you working/what toolchain are you using?

Comment: That's not really C-related. ISA instruction are something that is generated from code in any language. Tools able to count these (if exist) will work equally well with programs written in any language.

Comment: That is not possible within C. You might be able to find a third-party tool which should be able to count executed instructions. May be valgrind family of tools?

Comment: It is unlikely a course would ask you to do this without providing the necessary tools except for very short routines using limited operations which had been discussed in class. In the latter case, count manually. In the former case, use the tools. Many processors have debugging or performance monitoring facilities that will count instructions. Using them is highly dependent on the hardware and the operating system.

Comment: The most "universal" way I can think of (not that there is a ready to use tool for your specific case though) is to use an emulated environment which is interpreting your program according to the given ISA an simulating the execution of the program and counting the instructions.

Comment: One way is to use `gdb` in single step mode. You can divert the output to a file and feed it `si` [step single ISA instruction] commands until it exits. From the output file, you can see what happened. To feed it many `si` commands, you could write a control program that runs `gdb` under two pipes. The control program sends `si` to `gdb` and grabs the output of `gdb`, counting the instructions. To get things started, you'll probably need to start with `b _start`, then `run`, then `si` ...

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628002/counting-machine-instructions-using-gdb) is how @CraigEstey.. shall we make it duplicate?

Comment: @CraigEstey: If I recall correctly, gdb has some counter of remaining repetitions, so you can execute `10000si` and then, if the program completes, check the counter to see how many remain. But executing in single-step mode is generally very slow.

Comment: @CraigEstey
As it was mentioned already single-stepping makes things incredibly slow (3 or 4 orders of magnitude) and any reasonable size program would run forever. It is [highly] not recommended to use this if the program runtime exceeds 10s of milliseconds.

Answer (score 15):

Terminology: what you're asking for is *dynamic* instruction count.  e.g. counting an instruction inside a loop every time it's executed.  This is usually roughly correlated with performance, but instructions-per-cycle can vary wildly.

- [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899)
- [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)

Something people also look at is *static* instruction count (or more usually just code-size, because that's what really matters for instruction-cache footprint, and disk-load times).  For variable-length instruction sets like x86, those are correlated but not the same thing.  On a RISC with fixed-length instructions, like MIPS or AArch64, it's closer but you still have padding for alignment of the start of functions, for example.  That's a totally separate metric.  `gcc -Os` optimizes for code-size while trying not to sacrifice to much speed.

---

If you're on Linux, use `gcc -O2 foo.c` to compile your code.  `-O2` doesn't enable auto-vectorization for gcc.  (It does for clang).  It's probably a good baseline level of optimization that will get rid of stuff in your C code that doesn't actually need to happen, to avoid silly differences between using more or fewer tmp variables to break up a big expression.  Maybe use `-Og` if you want minimal optimization, or `-O0` if you want really dumb braindead code that compiles each statement separately and never keeps anything in registers between statements.  ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-for-this-simple-floating-point-sum-with)).

Yes, it matters a *huge* amount *how* you compile.  `gcc -O3 -march=native -ffast-math` might use a lot fewer instructions, if it auto-vectorizes a loop.

To stop your code from optimizing away, take an input from a command-line arg, or read it from a `volatile` variable.  Like `volatile int size_volatile = 1234;`  `int size = size_volatile;`.  And return or print a result, because if the program has no side-effects then the most efficient implementation is to just exit immediately.

---

Then run **`perf stat ./a.out`**.  That will use hardware performance counters to give you total instructions executed on behalf of your process.  (Along with other counters, like CPU core clock cycles, and some software counters like `page-faults` and time in microseconds.)

**To count only user-space instructions, use `perf stat -e instructions:u ./a.out`**.  (Or in recent perf versions, `perf stat --all-user ./a.out` to apply :u to all events, even the default set.)  Each hardware event counter has 2 bits that indicate whether it should be counting events in user, supervisor, or both, so the kernel's perf code doesn't have to run an instruction to stop counters for `:u` events or anything like that.

**That will still be a very big number even for a simple "hello world" program, like 180k** if built normally, because that includes dynamic-linker startup and all the code that runs inside library functions.  And CRT startup code that calls your `main`, and that makes an `exit` system call with `main`'s return value, if you return instead of calling `exit(3)`.

**You might statically link your C program to reduce that startup overhead, by compiling with `gcc -O2 -static -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie`**

---

**`perf` counting `instructions:u`** seems to be pretty accurate on my Skylake CPU.  A statically-linked x86-64 **binary that contains only 2 instructions gets 3 counts.**  Apparently there's one extra instruction being counted in the transition between kernel and user mode in one direction, but that's pretty minor.

```
$ cat > exit.asm <<EOF
global _start       ; hand-written asm to check perf overhead
_start:
    mov eax, 231     ; _NR_exit_group
    syscall          ; exit_group(EDI) (in practice zero)
EOF
$ nasm -felf64 exit.asm && ld -o exit  exit.o   # static executable, no CRT or libc
$ perf stat -e instructions:u ./exit

 Performance counter stats for './exit':

                 3      instructions:u                                              

       0.000651529 seconds time elapsed

# for this 2-instruction hand-written program
```

Using `ld` on its own is somewhat similar to linking with `gcc -nostdlib -static` (which also implies `-no-pie`; [static-pie is a separate thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553723/whats-the-difference-between-statically-linked-and-not-a-dynamic-executable))

---

#### Minimal instruction count for a C program with CRT and libc: about 33k

**A statically-linked binary made by the C compiler that calls `puts` twice counts `33,202   instructions:u`**.  I compiled with `gcc -O2 -static -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie hello.c`.

Seems reasonable for glibc init functions, including stdio, and CRT startup stuff before calling `main`.  (`main` itself only has 8 instructions, which I checked with `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out | less`).

If main just exited without printing, or especially if it called `_exit(0)` or `exit_group(0)` (the [raw system calls, bypassing atexit stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit)), you'd have fewer instructions from not using stdio.

---

## Other resources:

- [Number of executed Instructions different for Hello World program Nasm Assembly and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208824/number-of-executed-instructions-different-for-hello-world-program-nasm-assembly/35210404#35210404)

  @MichaelPetch's answer shows how to use an alternate libc (MUSL) that doesn't need startup code to run for its `printf` to work.  So you can compile a C program and set its `main` as the ELF entry point (and call `_exit()` instead of returning).
- [How can I profile C++ code running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-can-i-profile-c-code-running-on-linux) There are tons of profiling tools for finding hotspots, and expensive functions (including the time spent in functions they call, i.e. stack backtrace profiling).  Mostly this isn't about counting instructions, though.

---

### Binary instrumentation tools:

These are the heavy duty tools for counting instructions, including counting only specific kinds of instructions.

- [Intel Pin - A Dynamic Binary Instrumentation Tool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool)
- [Intel® Software Development Emulator (SDE)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator)  This is based on PIN, and is handy for things like testing AVX512 code on a dev machine that doesn't support AVX512.  (It dynamically recompiles so most instructions run natively, but unsupported instructions call an emulation routine.)

  For example, **`sde64 -mix -- ./my_program`** will print an instruction-mix for your program, with total counts for each different instruction, and breakdowns by categories.  See [libsvm compiled with AVX vs no AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689918/libsvm-compiled-with-avx-vs-no-avx) for an example of the kind of output.

  It also gives you a table of total dynamic instruction counts per-function, as well as per-thread and global.  **SDE mix output doesn't work well on PIE executable, though**: it thinks the dynamic linker is the executable (because it is), so compile with `gcc -O2 -no-pie -fno-pie prog.c -o prog`.  It still doesn't see the `puts` calls or `main` itself in the profile output for a hello world test program, though, and I don't know why not.
- [Calculating “FLOP” using Intel® Software Development Emulator (Intel® SDE)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/calculating-flop-using-intel-software-development-emulator-intel-sde) An example of using SDE to count certain kinds of instructions, like `vfmadd231pd`.

  Intel CPUs have HW perf counters for events like `fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double`, so you can use those to count FLOPs instead.  They actually [count FMA as 2 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419438/fma-instruction-showing-up-as-three-packed-double-operations/54419796#54419796).  So if you have an Intel CPU that can run your code natively, you can do that instead with `perf stat -e -e fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double,fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_double`.  (And/or the events for single-precision.)

  But there aren't events for most other specific kinds of instructions, only FP math.

**This is all Intel stuff; IDK what AMD has, or any stuff for ISAs other than x86.  These are just the tools I've heard of; I'm sure there are lots of things I'm leaving out.**

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer but I wonder if it still applies? With the "hello, world" program (written in c++), compiled as  `g++ -O2 -static -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie main.cpp`, and tested with `sudo perf stat -e instructions:u ./a.out`, I count 72,084 instructions. I am on Linux 5.4.0-60, with a `i7-9750H`, CPU. Might I be doing something wrong?

Comment: @fabian: Yeah that sounds about right for CRT + glibc startup functions plus stdio's buffering code.  Note that my 3 example is for a *hand-written asm* program that defines its own `_start` and only makes an `exit` system call, like https://godbolt.org/z/EjMPj8.  If you want to see the instructions in your program, use `gdb ./a.out` and use `starti` to stop before the first user-space instruction.  From there, you can `stepi`.  (I'd recommend `layout asm` for this.)

Comment: @fabian: Oh, or were you comparing against my 33,202 count for a C program? Forgot that was also in my answer :P  Wait, you said `g++`.  Were you using `std::cout` iostream stuff?  It has its own init to do, separate from libc which still has to happen, and libstdc++ will also have some static constructors even if you don't use iostream.  (Its init is heavy enough that only `#include <iostream>` actually gets some of that init to happen. Note the constructor code compiled when you include iostream: try commenting it in https://godbolt.org/z/EqahcP. The linker merges so it only constructs once)

Comment: Thanks, @PeterCordes for your detailed comments! I measuring the number of instruction counts against the 3 instructions you mentioned, I did not fully appreciate/comprehend that you wrote this code manually. When writing the program in `c` with `stdio.h`, I also count about 30,000 instructions. The godbolt examples you mentioned were also instructive, in particular that the highly optimized empty main function has so many instructions - thank you very much!

Comment: @fabian: I remember thinking when I wrote this answer that I wasn't really happy with the clarity of what was being measured in that example code block; to easy for readers to miss that it was the hand-written asm test, not C compiler output, and not see the buried 33k number which is kind of a key point.  Anyway, updated to correct that since it turned out to be easy to misread in practice.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this could be to manually instrument each instruction with a counting instruction. There are several ways of doing this -

1. You could modify the Instruction emitter part of any open source compiler (gcc/LLVM) to emit a counting instruction before every instruction. I can add to the answer the exact way of doing this in LLVM if you are interested. But I believe that the second method I am giving here will be easier to implement and will work across most compilers.
2. You can instrument the instructions post compilation. Most compilers provide the option to generate readable assembly instead of the object files. The flag for gcc/clang is `-S`.
   For the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main_real(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

my compiler produces the following `.s` file -

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _main_real                  ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main_real:                                  ## @main_real
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rax
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "hello world\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

It is easy to see here that everything that starts with `<tab>` not followed by a `.` is an instruction.

Now we have to simple program that finds all such instructions and instrument them. You can do this easily with `perl`.
But before we actually instrument the code, we have to figure out an appropriate instrumenting instruction. This will depend a lot on the architecture and the target operating system. So I will provide an example for X86_64.

It is clear why we need to instrument BEFORE the instructions rather than AFTER them, so as to also count the branching instructions.

Assuming a global variables `__r13_save` and `__instruction_counter` initialized to zero, we can insert the instruction -

```
movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
leaq 1(%r13), %r13
movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
```

As you can see we have used the `rip` relative addressing mode, which should be fine for most programs that a beginner writes (bigger programs might have issues). 
We have used `leaq` here instead of `incq` to avoid clobbering the flags that are used by the program for control flow. (As suggested by @PeterCordes in the comments.)

This instrumentation also works correctly for single threaded programs since we are using a global counter for instructions and stashing away the `%r13` register. For extending the above for multithreaded program, one will have to use thread local storage and instrument the thread creation functions too.

Also, the variables `__r13_save` and `__instruction_counter` are frequently accessed and should always be in the L1 cache, making this instrumentation not that costly.

Now to instrument the instructions we use perl as -

```
cat input.s | perl -pe 's/^(\t[^.])/\tmovq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)\n\tmovq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13\n\tleaq 1(%r13), %r13\n\tmovq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)\n\tmovq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)\n\1/' > output.s
```

For the above sample program this generates

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _main_real              ## -- Begin function main_real
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main_real:                             ## @main_real
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rax
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movb    $0, %al
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    callq   _printf
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    addq    $32, %rsp
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    popq    %rbp
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    movq __instruction_counter(%rip), %r13
    leaq 1(%r13), %r13
    movq %r13, __instruction_counter(%rip)
    movq %r13, __r13_save(%rip)
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "hello world\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Now we also need to create this variable somewhere. This can be done by creating a simple c wrapper.c as -

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long int __instruction_counter;
long long int __r13_save;
int main_real(int, char* []);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int ret = main_real(argc, argv);
    printf("Total instructions = %lld\n", __instruction_counter);
    return ret;
}
```

You might see the function `main_real`. So in your actual program you have to create a `main_real` instead of `main`.

Finally link everything up as -

```
clang output.s wrapper.c -o a.out
```

and execute your program. Your code should run normally and print the instruction count before it exits.

You might have to take care of name mangling of the `__instruction_counter` variable. For some ABIs the compiler adds an extra `_` at the beginning. In that case you will have to add an extra `_` to the perl command. You can check the exact name for the variable by also generating the assembly for the wrapper.

On running the above example I get -

```
hello world
Total instructions = 15
```

Which matches the exact number of instruction our function has. 
You might have noticed that this counts only the number of instructions in the code you have written and compiled. Not in the `printf` function for instance. That is usually a difficult problem to tackle with static instrumentation.

One caveat here is that your program has to exit "normally" i.e. by returning from `main`. If it calls `exit` or `abort`, you will not be able to see the instruction count. You can also provide an instrumented version of `exit` and `abort` to solve that problem.

With a compiler based approach this can be made more efficient by adding a single `addq` instruction for each basic block with the parameter being the number of instruction that BB has, since once the control flow enters a basic block, it is bound to go through it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187298/discussion-on-answer-by-ajay-brahmakshatriya-how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-x8).

Comment: Minor point: `__r13_cache` isn't a cache, it's a save area.  So a name like `__saved_r13` might be good.

Comment: @PeterCordes sure, reworded!

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my top comments, one way to do this is to write a program that feeds commands to `gdb`.

Specifically, the `si` command (step ISA instruction).

I couldn't get this to work with pipes, but I was able to get it to work by putting `gdb` under a pseudo-tty.

**Edit:** After thinking about it, I came up with a version that uses `ptrace` directly on the target program instead of sending commands to `gdb`. It is *much* faster [100x faster] and [probably] more reliable

---

So, here's the `gdb` based control program. Note that this must be linked with `-lutil`.

```
// gdbctl -- gdb control via pseudo tty

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int opt_d;                              // 1=show debug output
int opt_e;                              // 1=echo gdb output
int opt_f;                              // 1=set line buffered output
int opt_x;                              // si repetition factor

int zpxlvl;                             // current trace level

int ptypar;                             // parent PTY fd
int ptycld;                             // child PTY fd
char name[100];                         // child PTY device name

unsigned long long sicount;             // single step count

const char *gdb = "(gdb) ";             // gdb's prompt string
const char *waitstr;                    // currently active "wait for" string
char *waitstop[8] = { NULL };           // string that shows run is done

int stopflg;                            // 1=waitstop seen
char sicmd[100];

char waitbuf[10000];                    // large buffer to scan for strings
char *waitdst = waitbuf;                // current end position

pid_t pidgdb;                           // gdb's pid
pid_t pidfin;                           // stop pid
int status;                             // gdb's final status
double tvelap;                          // start time

#ifndef _USE_ZPRT_
#define _USE_ZPRT_      1
#endif

static inline int
zprtok(int lvl)
{

    return (_USE_ZPRT_ && (opt_d >= lvl));
}

#define dbg(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (zprtok(_lvl)) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

// tvgetf -- get high precision time
double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

// xstrcat -- concatenate a string
char *
xstrcat(char *dst,const char *src)
{
    int chr;

    for (chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++)
        *dst++ = chr;

    *dst = 0;

    return dst;
}

// gdbexit -- check for gdb termination
void
gdbexit(void)
{

    // NOTE: this should _not_ happen
    do {
        if (pidgdb == 0)
            break;

        pidfin = waitpid(pidgdb,&status,WNOHANG);
        if (pidfin == 0)
            break;

        pidgdb = 0;
        printf("gdbexit: WAITPID status=%8.8X\n",status);
        exit(8);
    } while (0);
}

// gdbwaitpoll -- wait for prompt string
void
gdbwaitpoll(const char *buf)
{
    char *cp;
    char **wstr;

    do {
        gdbexit();

        if (waitstr == NULL)
            break;

        // concatenate to big buffer
        dbg(2,"BUF '%s'\n",buf);
        waitdst = xstrcat(waitdst,buf);

        // check for final termination string (e.g. "exited with")
        for (wstr = waitstop;  *wstr != NULL;  ++wstr) {
            cp = *wstr;
            dbg(2,"TRYSTOP '%s'\n",cp);
            cp = strstr(waitbuf,cp);
            if (cp != NULL) {
                stopflg = 1;
                waitstop[0] = NULL;
            }
        }

        // check for the prompt (e.g. "(gdb) ")
        cp = strstr(waitbuf,waitstr);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        dbg(1,"HIT on '%s'\n",waitstr);

        // got it reset things
        waitbuf[0] = 0;
        waitdst = waitbuf;
        waitstr = NULL;
    } while (0);
}

// gdbrecv -- process input from gdb
void
gdbrecv(void)
{
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    struct pollfd *fd = &fds[0];
    int xlen;
    char buf[1000];

    fd->fd = ptypar;
    fd->events = POLLIN;

    while (1) {
        gdbexit();

#if 1
        int nfd = poll(fds,1,1);
        if (nfd <= 0) {
            if (waitstr != NULL)
                continue;
            break;
        }
#endif

        // get a chunk of data
        xlen = read(ptypar,buf,sizeof(buf) - 1);
        dbg(1,"gdbrecv: READ xlen=%d\n",xlen);

        if (xlen < 0) {
            printf("ERR: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        // wait until we've drained every bit of data
        if (xlen == 0) {
            if (waitstr != NULL)
                continue;
            break;
        }

        // add EOS char
        buf[xlen] = 0;

        dbg(1,"ECHO: ");
        if (opt_e)
            fwrite(buf,1,xlen,stdout);

        // wait for our prompt
        gdbwaitpoll(buf);
    }
}

// gdbwaitfor -- set up prompt string to wait for
void
gdbwaitfor(const char *wstr,int loopflg)
{

    waitstr = wstr;
    if (waitstr != NULL)
        dbg(1,"WAITFOR: '%s'\n",waitstr);

    while ((waitstr != NULL) && loopflg && (pidgdb != 0))
        gdbrecv();
}

// gdbcmd -- send command to gdb
void
gdbcmd(const char *str,const char *wstr)
{
    int rlen = strlen(str);
    int xlen = 0;

#if 0
    printf("CMD/%d: %s",rlen,str);
#endif

    gdbwaitfor(wstr,0);

    for (;  rlen > 0;  rlen -= xlen, str += xlen) {
        gdbexit();

        xlen = write(ptypar,str,rlen);
        if (xlen <= 0)
            break;

        dbg(1,"RET: rlen=%d xlen=%d\n",rlen,xlen);
        gdbrecv();
    }

    dbg(1,"END/%d\n",xlen);
}

// gdbctl -- control gdb
void
gdbctl(int argc,char **argv)
{

    // this is the optimal number for speed
    if (opt_x < 0)
        opt_x = 100;

    if (opt_x <= 1) {
        opt_x = 1;
        sprintf(sicmd,"si\n");
    }
    else
        sprintf(sicmd,"si %d\n",opt_x);

    // create pseudo TTY
    openpty(&ptypar,&ptycld,name,NULL,NULL);

    pidgdb = fork();

    // launch gdb
    if (pidgdb == 0) {
        //sleep(1);

        login_tty(ptycld);
        close(ptypar);

        char *gargs[8];
        char **gdst = gargs;

        *gdst++ = "gdb";
        *gdst++ = "-n";
        *gdst++ = "-q";
        *gdst++ = *argv;
        *gdst = NULL;

        execvp(gargs[0],gargs);
        exit(9);
    }

    // make input from gdb non-blocking
#if 1
    int flags = fcntl(ptypar,F_GETFL,0);
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(ptypar,F_SETFL,flags);
#endif

    // wait
    char **wstr = waitstop;
    *wstr++ = "exited with code";
    *wstr++ = "Program received signal";
    *wstr++ = "Program terminated with signal";
    *wstr = NULL;

    printf("TTY: %s\n",name);
    printf("SI: %d\n",opt_x);
    printf("GDB: %d\n",pidgdb);

#if 1
    sleep(2);
#endif

    gdbwaitfor(gdb,1);

    // prevent kill or quit commands from hanging
    gdbcmd("set confirm off\n",gdb);

    // set breakpoint at earliest point
#if 1
    gdbcmd("b _start\n",gdb);
#else
    gdbcmd("b main\n",gdb);
#endif

    // skip over target program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // add extra arguments
    do {
        if (argc <= 0)
            break;

        char xargs[1000];
        char *xdst = xargs;
        xdst += sprintf(xdst,"set args");

        for (int avidx = 0;  avidx < argc;  ++avidx, ++argv) {
            printf("XARGS: '%s'\n",*argv);
            xdst += sprintf(xdst," %s",*argv);
        }

        xdst += sprintf(xdst,"\n");

        gdbcmd(xargs,gdb);
    } while (0);

    // run the program -- it will stop at the breakpoint we set
    gdbcmd("run\n",gdb);

    // disable the breakpoint for speed
    gdbcmd("disable\n",gdb);

    tvelap = tvgetf();

    while (1) {
        // single step an ISA instruction
        gdbcmd(sicmd,gdb);

        // check for gdb aborting
        if (pidgdb == 0)
            break;

        // check for target program exiting
        if (stopflg)
            break;

        // advance count of ISA instructions
        sicount += opt_x;
    }

    // get elapsed time
    tvelap = tvgetf() - tvelap;

    // tell gdb to quit
    gdbcmd("quit\n",NULL);

    // wait for gdb to completely terminate
    if (pidgdb != 0) {
        pidfin = waitpid(pidgdb,&status,0);
        pidgdb = 0;
    }

    // close PTY units
    close(ptypar);
    close(ptycld);
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'd':
            cp += 2;
            opt_d = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'e':
            cp += 2;
            opt_e = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'f':
            cp += 2;
            opt_f = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'x':
            cp += 2;
            opt_x = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : -1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc == 0) {
        printf("specify target program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // set output line buffering
    switch (opt_f) {
    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        setlinebuf(stdout);
        break;

    default:
        setbuf(stdout,NULL);
        break;
    }

    gdbctl(argc,argv);

    // print statistics
    printf("%llu instructions -- ELAPSED: %.9f -- %.3f insts / sec\n",
        sicount,tvelap,(double) sicount / tvelap);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a sample test program:

```
// tgt -- sample slave/test program

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int opt_S;

int glob;

void
dumb(int x)
{

    glob += x;
}

int
spin(int lim)
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0;  x < lim;  ++x)
        dumb(x);

    return x;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    int lim;
    int *ptr;
    int code;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'S':
            opt_S = cp[2];
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (opt_S) {
    case 'f':  // cause segfault
        ptr = NULL;
        *ptr = 23;
        code = 91;
        break;

    case 'a':  // abort
        abort();
        code = 92;
        break;

    case 't':  // terminate us
        signal(SIGTERM,SIG_DFL);
#if 0
        kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);
#else
        raise(SIGTERM);
#endif
        code = 93;
        break;

    default:
        code = 0;
        break;
    }

    if (argc > 0)
        lim = atoi(argv[0]);
    else
        lim = 10000;

    lim = spin(lim);
    lim &= 0x7F;
    if (code == 0)
        code = lim;

    return code;
}
```

---

Here's a version that uses `ptrace` that is *much* faster than the version that uses `gdb`:

```
// ptxctl -- control via ptrace

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

int opt_d;                              // 1=show debug output
int opt_e;                              // 1=echo progress
int opt_f;                              // 1=set line buffered output

unsigned long long sicount;             // single step count

int stopflg;                            // 1=stop seen

pid_t pidtgt;                           // gdb's pid
pid_t pidfin;                           // stop pid

int status;                             // target's final status
char statbuf[1000];                     // status buffer
int coredump;                           // 1=core dumped

int zpxlvl;                             // current trace level

int regsidx;                            // regs index
struct user_regs_struct regs[2];        // current regs

#define REGSALL(_cmd) \
    _cmd(r15) \
    _cmd(r14) \
    _cmd(r13) \
    _cmd(r12) \
    _cmd(rbp) \
    _cmd(rbx) \
    _cmd(r11) \
    _cmd(r10) \
    _cmd(r9) \
    _cmd(r8) \
    _cmd(rax) \
    _cmd(rcx) \
    _cmd(rdx) \
    _cmd(rsi) \
    _cmd(rdi) \
    _cmd(orig_rax) \
    /*_cmd(rip)*/ \
    _cmd(cs) \
    _cmd(eflags) \
    _cmd(rsp) \
    _cmd(ss) \
    _cmd(fs_base) \
    _cmd(gs_base) \
    _cmd(ds) \
    _cmd(es) \
    _cmd(fs) \
    _cmd(gs)

#define REGSDIF(_reg) \
    if (cur->_reg != prev->_reg) \
        printf("  %16.16llX " #_reg "\n",cur->_reg);

double tvelap;                          // start time

#ifndef _USE_ZPRT_
#define _USE_ZPRT_      1
#endif

static inline int
zprtok(int lvl)
{

    return (_USE_ZPRT_ && (opt_d >= lvl));
}

#define dbg(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (zprtok(_lvl)) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

// tvgetf -- get high precision time
double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

// ptxstatus -- decode status
char *
ptxstatus(int status)
{
    int zflg;
    int signo;
    char *bp;

    bp = statbuf;
    *bp = 0;

    // NOTE: do _not_ use zprtok here -- we need to force this on final
    zflg = (opt_d >= zpxlvl);

    do {
        if (zflg)
            bp += sprintf(bp,"%8.8X",status);

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            signo = WSTOPSIG(status);
            if (zflg)
                bp += sprintf(bp," WIFSTOPPED signo=%d",signo);

            switch (signo) {
            case SIGTRAP:
                break;
            default:
                stopflg = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            if (zflg)
                bp += sprintf(bp," WIFEXITED code=%d",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            stopflg = 1;
        }

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            signo = WTERMSIG(status);
            if (zflg)
                bp += sprintf(bp," WIFSIGNALED signo=%d",signo);

            if (WCOREDUMP(status)) {
                coredump = 1;
                stopflg = 1;
                if (zflg)
                    bp += sprintf(bp," -- core dumped");
            }
        }
    } while (0);

    return statbuf;
}

// ptxcmd -- issue ptrace command
long
ptxcmd(enum __ptrace_request cmd,void *addr,void *data)
{
    long ret;

    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxcmd: ENTER cmd=%d addr=%p data=%p\n",cmd,addr,data);
    ret = ptrace(cmd,pidtgt,addr,data);
    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxcmd: EXIT ret=%ld\n",ret);

    return ret;
}

// ptxwait -- wait for target to be stopped
void
ptxwait(const char *reason)
{

    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxwait: %s pidtgt=%d\n",reason,pidtgt);
    pidfin = waitpid(pidtgt,&status,0);

    // NOTE: we need this to decide on stop status
    ptxstatus(status);

    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxwait: %s status=(%s) pidfin=%d\n",
        reason,statbuf,pidfin);
}

// ptxwhere -- show where we are
void
ptxwhere(int initflg)
{
    struct user_regs_struct *cur;
    struct user_regs_struct *prev;

    do {
        prev = &regs[regsidx];

        if (initflg) {
            ptxcmd(PTRACE_GETREGS,NULL,prev);
            break;
        }

        regsidx = ! regsidx;
        cur = &regs[regsidx];

        ptxcmd(PTRACE_GETREGS,NULL,cur);
        printf("RIP: %16.16llX (%llu)\n",cur->rip,sicount);

        if (opt_e < 2)
            break;

        REGSALL(REGSDIF);
    } while (0);
}

// ptxctl -- control ptrace
void
ptxctl(int argc,char **argv)
{

    pidtgt = fork();

    // launch target program
    if (pidtgt == 0) {
        pidtgt = getpid();
        ptxcmd(PTRACE_TRACEME,NULL,NULL);
        execvp(argv[0],argv);
        exit(9);
    }

#if 0
    sleep(1);
#endif

    zpxlvl = 1;

#if 0
    ptxwait("SETUP");
#endif

    // attach to tracee
    // NOTE: we do _not_ need to do this because child has done TRACEME
#if 0
    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxctl: PREATTACH\n");
    ptxcmd(PTRACE_ATTACH,NULL,NULL);
    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxctl: POSTATTACH\n");
#endif

    // wait for initial stop
#if 1
    ptxwait("INIT");
#endif

    if (opt_e)
        ptxwhere(1);

    dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxctl: START\n");

    tvelap = tvgetf();

    zpxlvl = 2;

    while (1) {
        dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxctl: SINGLESTEP\n");
        ptxcmd(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP,NULL,NULL);
        ptxwait("WAIT");

        sicount += 1;

        // show where we are
        if (opt_e)
            ptxwhere(0);

        dbg(zpxlvl,"ptxctl: STEPCOUNT sicount=%lld\n",sicount);

        // stop when target terminates
        if (stopflg)
            break;
    }

    zpxlvl = 0;
    ptxstatus(status);
    printf("ptxctl: STATUS (%s) pidfin=%d\n",statbuf,pidfin);

    // get elapsed time
    tvelap = tvgetf() - tvelap;
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'd':
            cp += 2;
            opt_d = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'e':
            cp += 2;
            opt_e = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'f':
            cp += 2;
            opt_f = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc == 0) {
        printf("specify target program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // set output line buffering
    switch (opt_f) {
    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        setlinebuf(stdout);
        break;

    default:
        setbuf(stdout,NULL);
        break;
    }

    ptxctl(argc,argv);

    // print statistics
    printf("%llu instructions -- ELAPSED: %.9f -- %.3f insts / sec\n",
        sicount,tvelap,(double) sicount / tvelap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have been able to interface `python` with `gdb` using subprocess in the past to exactly send a fixed number of si's.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, python is _the_ scripting language to control `gdb`. But, here, I also wanted to experiment with pseudo-tty control of an arbitrary program (i.e. a generalization of what I posted here). And, my python is quite beginner level.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I came up with a new version that uses `ptrace` directly and it is 100x faster than using `gdb`

Comment: Ah yes, that is expected because `gdb` anyway uses `ptrace` internally while with the `gdb` method you are adding the overhead of parsing commands. And I believe `gdb` must be doing a lot of book keeping, which is not required for just counting instructions.

Comment: I also timed the version in my answer. For the sample program you provided the execution time goes from `3.676` seconds to `43.070` seconds with `lim` as 10 billion and `gcc`s default optimization. So that is roughly 11.71 times overhead. What kind of overheads (% overhead) are you seeing with `ptrace`? I think it would be more because of the context switch between the child and parent process after each instruction.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, I actually took a look at `gdb` _source_ and even when you say `si 1000`, it [still] does a lot of _overly_ elaborate stuff underneath. The `gdb` version _without_ a repetition factor is ~500 insts / sec. With repetition: `-x10` --> 2500/sec `-x100` --> 3700 and `-x1000` --> 3900, so the sweet spot is between 10 and 100. The `ptrace` version is 150,000 inst/sec

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#) to compile your program and display the assembly code for various compilers and options.

Then count the number of instructions for every fragment, ie: sequence of statements upto and including the first test.

Then instrument you code: add a global variable `instruction_count`, initialized to the number of instructions in the `main` function epilog and increment this variable at the beginning of each fragment by the number of instructions you counted in the previous step. and print this number just before returning from the `main` function.

You will get the number of instructions that would be executed by the uninstrumented program for whatever input is provided to the program, for a given combination of architecture, compiler and options, but not including instructions executed in library functions nor during the startup and exit phases.