# How do I monitor the amount of SIMD instruction usage

Tags: linux, intel, cpu-usage

How can I monitor the amount of SIMD (SSE, AVX, AVX2, AVX-512) instruction usage of a process? For example, `htop` can be used to monitor general CPU usage, but not specifically SIMD instruction usage.

Comment: vtune is usually your best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only reliable way to count *all* SIMD instructions (not just FP math) is dynamic instrumentation (e.g. via something like Intel PIN / SDE).

See [How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243626/how-to-characterize-a-workload-by-obtaining-the-instruction-type-breakdown) and [How do I determine the number of x86 machine instructions executed in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355631/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-x86-machine-instructions-executed-in-a-c-progra) specifically **`sde64 -mix -- ./my_program` to print the instruction mix for your program** for that run, example output in [libsvm compiled with AVX vs no AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689918/libsvm-compiled-with-avx-vs-no-avx)

I don't think there's a good way to make this like `top` / `htop`, if it's even possible to safely attach to already-running processes, especially multi-threaded once.

It might also be possible to get dynamic instruction counts using last-branch-record stuff to record / reconstruct the path of execution and count everything, but I don't know of tools for that.  In theory that could attach to already-running programs without much danger, but **it would take a lot of computation (disassembling and counting instructions) to do it on the fly for all running processes**.  Not like just asking the kernel for CPU usage stats that it tracks anyway on context switches.

You'd need hardware instruction-counting support for this to be really efficient the way `top` is.

---

For SIMD *floating point math* specifically (not FP shuffles, just real FP math like `vaddps`), there are perf counter events.

e.g. from `perf list` output:

> `fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_single`
>         [Number of SSE/AVX computational 128-bit packed single precision
>           floating-point instructions retired. **Each count represents 4
>           computations**. Applies to SSE* and AVX* packed single precision
>           floating-point instructions: ADD SUB MUL DIV MIN MAX RCP RSQRT SQRT
>           DPP FM(N)ADD/SUB. DPP and FM(N)ADD/SUB instructions count twice as
>           they perform multiple calculations per element]

So it's not even counting uops, it's counting FLOPS.  There are other events for `...pd` packed double, and 256-bit versions of each.  (I assume on CPUs with AVX512, there are also 512-bit vector versions of these events.)

You can use `perf` to count their execution globally across processes and on all cores.  Or for a single process

```
## count math instructions only, not SIMD integer, load/store, or anything else
perf stat -e cycles:u,instructions:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.{128,256}b_packed_{double,single}:u  ./my_program
# fixme: that brace-expansion doesn't expand properly; it separates with spaces not commas.
```

(Intentionally omitting `fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_{double,single}` because you only asked about SIMD and scalar instructions on XMM registers don't count, IMO.)

(**You can attach `perf` to a running process by using `-p PID` instead of a command.**  Or **use `perf top`** as suggested in 
See [Ubuntu - how to tell if AVX or SSE, is current being used by CPU app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329437/ubuntu-how-to-tell-if-avx-or-sse-is-current-being-used-by-cpu-app)

You can run `perf stat -a` to monitor globally across all cores, regardless of what process is executing.  But again, this only counts FP math, not SIMD in general.

Still, it is hardware-supported and thus could be cheap enough for something like `htop` to use without wasting a lot of CPU time if you leave it running long-term.