# How can I get the Perf working in an Azure VM?

Tags: linux, azure, profiling, azure-virtual-machine, perf

I am trying to profile an application inside an Azure VM (Ubuntu 18.04) using the *perf*. But the *perf stats* doesn't provide all the statistics.

```
Performance counter stats for 'ls':

          0.78 msec task-clock                #    0.760 CPUs utilized          
             1      context-switches          #    0.001 M/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           106      page-faults               #    0.135 M/sec                  
<not supported>      cycles                                                      
<not supported>      instructions                                                
<not supported>      branches                                                    
<not supported>      branch-misses                                               

   0.001031061 seconds time elapsed

   0.001016000 seconds user
   0.000000000 seconds sys
```

And, also the `perf list` doesn't list any hardware events.

```
List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
bpf-output                                         [Software event]
context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
dummy                                              [Software event]
emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
major-faults                                       [Software event]
minor-faults                                       [Software event]
page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
task-clock                                         [Software event]

duration_time                                      [Tool event]

msr/pperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]

rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
```

I read that the CPU performance counters are not enabled for the VMs [source](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-F920A3C7-3B42-4E78-8EA7-961E49AF479D.html).

Is it possible to enable the hardware events in Azure VM? or is there any other way to find the instructions used while executing an application?

Comment: Most VMs don't virtualize and pass through the PMU HW performance counters.  I think Linux KVM was working on it, but IDK if even that is done yet.

Comment: If you don't care about timing, just counting instructions, you could use dynamic instrumentation or emulation.  e.g. Intel's SDE has an instruction-mix counter that can even break things down by mnemonic.  See [How do I monitor the amount of SIMD instruction usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60104698) for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your input. I will try dynamic instrumentation.

Comment: @Naren are you possibly able to write an answer outlining your dynamic instrumentation tests in detail? Or didn't this work out as expected?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

> is there any other way to find the instructions used while executing an application?

**Answer:**
If you have time or can adjust the application to limit the checking to only parts of the program, then valgrind's callgrind tool will get you very accurate numbers, along with a deep analysis option (inspecting the call profile via kachegrind, for example); but applications using this commonly take 10-20x longer, which may be a big problem (`perf stat -e instructions` don't do much, if anything to the time taken).

**Side-question**: is `perf` usable on local virtual machines / cloud virtual guests?
It definitely is, but not on all configurations (and if you can't change the virtualization settings, like it seems to be the case for most Azure environments [only works if you can adjust the Hyper-V configuration or get those adjusted (please drop a comment if you found a way for that as I haven't)], you can't get perf counters).
Belong the known setups are Qemu, VMWare and others - in general you can check [the documentation for VMs with RR](https://github.com/rr-debugger/rr/wiki/Building-And-Installing#virtual-machine-guests), as this software works on hardware counters, too.