# Most frequently used instructions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, arm64, instructions

Every now and then I read somewhere that of all of the instruction a CPU has only very few are used most of the time, last time it was [here](https://dougallj.wordpress.com/2022/11/09/why-is-rosetta-2-fast/) where the author writes: "There are only a handful of different instructions that account for 90% of all operations executed".

What are the most frequently used instructions? I'm most interested in x86-64 and arm64.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but instructions that deal with moving values between registers and the stack as well as branching have the highest usage. So maybe it would include RET, CALL, MOV, PUSH, POP, JE, JNE, and LEA. But I am probably missing a few really obvious ones.

Comment: @Locke: `add` and `cmp` will also be high up there in terms of instructions executed, probably also `sub` and `jmp`.  A lot of programs spend a lot of time branching as well as looping.  You can check with a simulator or trace tool that can total up instructions by mnemonic, such as Intel's SDE.  [How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58243626) / [Scan binary for CPU feature usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469653) (that quotes a different section of the SDE output, by extension not mnemonic)

Comment: [libsvm compiled with AVX vs no AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54689918) quotes an SDE log file for instruction mix for some random program.

Comment: You can easily work this out for yourself!  Decompile your chosen program, write a little sed script to extract just the instruction name, and then use uniq -c to count them  (I might do it for you myself later today if I have a spare half an hour).

Comment: @TomV: That would give you the *static* instruction count (by appearance in the file), not *dynamic* (how many times executed, counting loop bodies N times, counting unexecuted error handling block not at all).  It would probably be fairly similar for most programs, but anything with a bunch of configuration parsing and then a long computation phase might have differences.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Counting how often they are run requires using a profiler, and is much more involved.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to vary by operating system, compiler, compiler version, programming language, and possibly architecture extensions of the target you're looking at. It further depends on where you draw the line between what is or is not "the same" instruction.

On arm64, if you consider `movz w0, 0` and `movz w0, 1` to be different, then you can just take any binary, chunk it up into 4-byte blocks, print in hexadecimal and run that through `sort | uniq -c`.
If you consider all `movz` to be the same instruction, then the question arises whether `movz w0` and `movz x0` are the same. And if that is a yes, then there are other instructions like `add` that have different forms where the third operand is either a register or an immediate. And there's things like `ldr` with pre- and post-indexing modes that introduce additiona effects. And on top of all of that, there's pseudo-instructions like `mov` that can be encoded as either `movz`, `movn` or `orr`, depending on what the operands are.

But let's look at a concrete example: the `/bin/bash` binary on macOS 12.6.1.
The `__TEXT.__text` section of its arm64e slice has 118587 instructions. If we disassemble the entirety of it and try to normalise it by replacing all immediates with `...`, all general-purpose registers as well as `(w|x)zr` and `(w)sp` with `rN` and all floating-point registers with `fN` with this command:

```
perl -pe 's/b\.\w{2}/b.cond/g;s/\b(x[0-9]+|sp|xzr)\b/rN/g;s/\bw([0-9]+|sp|zr)/rN/g;s/\b[dq][0-9]+/fN/g;s/-?0x[0-9a-f]+/.../g;s/, -?\d+/, .../g;s/(lsl|lsr|asr|uxtw|sxtw) (\d+|0x[0-9a-f]+)/.../g;s/, \.\.\.\]/]/g'
```

And then sort the result by frequency with this:

```
sort | uniq -c | perl -pe 's/^\s+//g' | sort -V
```

And then choose an arbitrary cutoff at the `ret` instruction, we get:

```
265 ret
268 brk ...
269 autibsp
271 eor rN, rN, rN, ...
284 sub rN, rN, rN
299 cset rN, eq
312 cmn rN, ...
322 ldur rN, [rN]
332 add rN, rN, rN, ...
363 csel rN, rN, rN, eq
392 orr rN, rN, ...
432 paciza rN
450 ldr rN, [rN, rN]
476 strb rN, [rN]
507 ldp fN, fN, [rN]
578 sxtw rN, rN
745 and rN, rN, ...
780 tbnz rN, ..., ...
805 tbz rN, ..., ...
866 stp rN, rN, [rN]!
871 add rN, rN, rN
978 ldp rN, rN, [rN], ...
1028 invalid
1141 stp fN, fN, [rN]
1170 retab
1290 pacibsp
1457 sub rN, rN, ...
1520 cbnz rN, ...
1567 cmp rN, rN
1622 ldrb rN, [rN]
1695 adrp rN, ...
2548 ldr rN, ...
3504 stp rN, rN, [rN]
3537 ldp rN, rN, [rN]
3996 adr rN, ...
4644 cmp rN, ...
4664 add rN, rN, ...
4728 cbz rN, ...
4966 b ...
5294 str rN, [rN]
5601 b.cond ...
7451 mov rN, ...
7691 nop
8270 ldr rN, [rN]
10181 bl ...
11585 mov rN, rN
```

This amounts to 112015 instructions, or 94.5% of the total. A few things stand out here:

- This is an "arm64e" binary, which is Apple's name for their ABI with pointer authentication. On a regular arm64 target, all `retab` would be `ret`, and `pacibsp`, `autibsp` and `paciza` would not be present at all.
- Almost all occurrences of `brk` are following an `autibsp`, which is a compiler change Apple was forced to make in order to address a structural weakness of the `FEAT_PAuth` architecture extension. The remaining occurrences are very likely invocations of `__builtin_trap()` in the source.
- `nop` is very common. This is due to PC-relative addressing, where the compiler emits two or three instructions like `adrp x0, ...; add x0, x0, ...`, which can then be optimised at link time to `adr x0, ...; nop` if the target address is close enough to the instruction. It is debatable whether nops "run" though, or whether they are just deleted from the instruction pipeline.
- `invalid` is very common. These are jump tables found after the functions that use them. They are data, not code, and thus never actually run.
- Floating-point registers only show up in two instructions: `stp` and `ldp`. The compiler commonly uses floating-point registers for memcpy and memset operations, for one because these registers can hold up to 128 bits, and for another because it avoids having to spill general-purpose registers, which are a lot more likely to have already been allocated than floating-point registers, at least in command-line binaries like `bash`. I would expect similar conditions in operating system kernels and embedded firmwares, but in graphics-related code or machine learning, this may look very different.
- The vast majority of `cmn` instructions check against the value `-1`. This is exceedingly likely a result of API design in C, and not inherent to the architecture.

And now it depends whether you wanna reduce some of these instructions or not. But by and large, I think the pattern is clear:

- Register moves
- Immediate construction
- Function calls
- Unconditional branches
- Conditional branches
- Register compares
- Memory loads
- Memory stores

make up for the vast majority of instructions, and it makes sense, because with these building blocks, you can do essentially anything. Almost all other instructions are some kind of optimisation on those, which are more niche and thus occur less often. The remaining instructions are architecture-specific and expose things you couldn't otherwise get, like `brk` or `msr`, but these are going to be even rarer. And this is likely to be the case no matter what architecture you look at.

Comment: You're looking at *static* instruction counts, how often they appear in the binary.  (Including the NOPs between functions that never execute even once.  NOPs for alignment before a loop do execute as the CPU enters the loop, but the instructions inside the loop execute N times more, where N is the average trip count.  The question asked for **dynamic** instruction counts, in terms of how often they're actually executed.  Other than NOPs (and of course `invalid`!!), the mix might be fairly similar to static, although error-handling code runs rarely and might have a somewhat different mix.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think OP wants dynamic instruction counts. They asked for the most "used" instructions. I take it to mean the most "written"/"generated" instructions. It makes no sense to me to say that `pause` is one of the most used instructions just because it's in a loop that runs billions of times...

Comment: @MargaretBloom: The question says they're trying to confirm the statement "There are only a handful of different instructions that account for 90% of all operations **executed**".  It's a statement about making the common case fast for CPU architects, I think, probably a lead-up to some RISC philosophising.  (I certainly hope `pause` isn't one of the most executed instructions, like in the top 10.  That would be a horrible amount of contention spin-waiting vs. useful work, badly architected multi-threading with huge contention and lack of fallback to sleep instead of spinning.)